# Recommendations Box not showing any results

Tags: facebook, plugins

I've been using Facebook's Recommendations Box plugin for a blog that we run for a client. We use the iframe version. It worked as expected until recently, when it began simply displaying "No recommendations for this website yet."

http://www.massvacation.com/blog/

I went to the developers reference for this plugin to try re-generating the code:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/recommendations/

However, the preview there also came up with "no recommendations". Curious, I tried plugging in some big-name sites that should definitely have results: bbc, buzzfeed, all of them showing nothing.

So my question is, is there something I'm doing wrong, or is there a problem on Facebook's end? Does anyone have this widget currently working properly somewhere?

Comment: even i had a similar issue.Time healed it.its a fb issue.wait for some time perhaps,max a week?

Comment: Yes, the problem eventually went away. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Michel suggested above, time resolved the problem without any further action on my end.